# I have an environment variable for LANG set in ~/.profile but it is not getting set

Tags: bash, environment-variables, locale

I want to set the locale.

I have this in my ~/.profile

```
#language
export LANG=en_GB.utf8
export TESTING123=en_GB.utf8
```

But when I type:

```
echo $LANG $TESTING123
```

I get (LANG not set, but TESTING123 is set )

```
en_US.utf8 en_GB.utf8
```

If I do `export LANG=en_GB.utf8` directly in the shell it all works

```
#export LANG=en_GB.utf8
#echo $LANG
en_GB.utf8
#locale
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

---

system is Debian 7.2, shell is bash.

Comment: Look like, someone else is overriding the variable. Can you add the line `echo $LANG > /tmp/test` just after export command ?

Answer (score 9):

There are many other initialization files where the variables may be set after applying your `.profile` such as `.bash_profile` `.bashrc` ...etc, or simply an other non standard file called from `.profile` itself. 
I suggest first you to look for every occurrences of your variables in your home directory :

```
grep "LANG=" .*
```

Answer (score 7):

In debian you set locales using the following command:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It will create the `/etc/default/locale` file and add only the `LANG` variable to it. If you want to customize all the `LC_*` variables, you can add them there as well:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=C
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Debian is a multi-user system, there must be a way for each user to have there own locale.

Comment: I'm using `openbox` and in my case I can set each of the `LC_*` and `LANG` variables in `~/.config/openbox/environment` by using `export`. If you are using a `gnome` desktop, you should check its option, I remember that there was something about setting a language somewhere in the control panel.

Answer (score 4):

Went through and figured this finally because it was driving me nuts having to do it manually, didn't seem right. On debian this can be done with the `update-locale` utility. The command

```
update-locale --reset
```

will cause the `/etc/default/locale` file to be ignored (it simply comments out the `LANG` variable); resulting in a `locale` of:

```
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

The command

```
update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

will set your `LANG` to... you guessed it `en_US.UTF-8` resulting in `locale` generating:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And finally just to cover all my bases...

```
update-locale LANG=C
```

will set your `LANG` to `C` resulting in `locale` outputting:

```
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Debian is a multi-user system, there must be a way for each user to have there own locale.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`; they will override `~/.profile`.

From `man bash`:

> When  bash  is  invoked **as an interactive login shell,** or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, 
>   and  `~/.profile`,  in  that order,  and  reads  and  executes  commands
>   **from the first one** that exists and is readable.

"As an interactive **login** shell" is significant, because interactive shells often are not login shells.  If you just change one of those files and start a new GUI terminal, for example, it won't apply.  It is only read when you actually log in.

---

Another possibility is that your LANG is being subsequently reset by the system wide `bashrc`; check to see if one is sourced in `~/.bashrc`, then, e.g.

```
grep LANG /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Sorry for not paying better attention!  I've added one other (long shot) possibility at the bottom.